# iTextSharp 5.5.6: Signature invalid with SwissSign USB token

Tags: itext

I read Bruno Lowagie's white paper: Digital Signatures for PDF documents.

I followed the examples and I was able to sign PDF's with my SwissSign USB token using MSCAPI. This line of code does the trick:

MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);

I am also passing the TSA client with the SwissSign TSA URL: tsa(dot)swisssign(dot)net

When I open the signed PDF in Acrobat Reader DC 2015, I get the error:

*Signature is invalid.*

*There are errors in the formatting or information contained in this signature*

*Signer's identity has not yet been verified*

*Signing time is from the clock on the signer's computer.*

When signing the PDF with the SwissSign tool everything looks fine: signature is valid.

I have put the PDF's here:

[invalid PDF - signed with iTextSharp 5.5.6](http://fitsch.com/hello-world_invalid_signed-with-itextsharp.pdf)

[valid PDF - signed with SwissSign tool](http://fitsch.com/hello-world_valid_signed-with-swiss-signer.pdf)

I have tried different combinations of hash algorithms, but without success. What am I missing?

Any help appreciated.

Best Regards,

Phil

Here is the full code:

```
    private void _sign_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = x509Store.Certificates;
        IList<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> chain = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>();
        X509Certificate2 pk = null;
        if (certificates.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < certificates.Count; i++)
            {
                if (certificates[i].FriendlyName == "Philipp Egger (Qualified Signature) .....")        // Phil Egger Signature Certificate
                {
                    pk = certificates[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

            X509Chain x509chain = new X509Chain();
            x509chain.Build(pk);

            foreach (X509ChainElement x509ChainElement in x509chain.ChainElements)
            {
                chain.Add(Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509ChainElement.Certificate));
            }
        }
        x509Store.Close();

        if (pk != null)
        {
            #region connect usb token
            ///////////////////
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)pk.PrivateKey;

            CspParameters cspp = new CspParameters();
            cspp.KeyContainerName = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
            cspp.ProviderName = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName;
            cspp.ProviderType = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType;

            cspp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt;
            System.Security.SecureString pwstr = new System.Security.SecureString();
            pwstr.AppendChar('x');
            pwstr.AppendChar('x');
            pwstr.AppendChar('x');
            cspp.KeyPassword = pwstr;

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp);
            rsa2.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
            // PIN is cached from now on and popup won't appear
            ///////////////////////
            #endregion

            IOcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
            ITSAClient tsaClient = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < chain.Count; i++)
            {
                Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = chain[i];
                String tsaUrl = CertificateUtil.GetTSAURL(cert);
                if (tsaUrl != null)
                {
                    tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (tsaClient == null)
            { 
                tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle("http://tsa.swisssign.net");
                //tsaClient = new MyTSAClientBouncyCastle("http://tsa.swisssign.net");      // set user-agent
            }

            IList<ICrlClient> crlList = new List<ICrlClient>();
            crlList.Add(new CrlClientOnline(chain));

            string pathSource = @"C:\Temp\test_to_sign.pdf";
            string pathTarget3 = @"C:\Temp\test_to_sign-signed3.pdf";

            // this.SignNew(pathSource, pathTarget1, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1, CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test", "Rheinau", crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0);
            // this.SignNew(pathSource, pathTarget2, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1, CryptoStandard.CADES, "Test", "Rheinau", crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0);
            this.SignNew(pathSource, pathTarget3, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test", "Rheinau", crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0);
            // this.SignNew(pathSource, pathTarget4, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, CryptoStandard.CADES, "Test", "Rheinau", crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0);
            // this.SignNew(pathSource, pathTarget5, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA384, CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test", "Rheinau", crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0);
            // this.SignNew(pathSource, pathTarget6, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA384, CryptoStandard.CADES, "Test", "Rheinau", crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0);
            // this.SignNew(pathSource, pathTarget7, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA512, CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test", "Rheinau", crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0);
            // this.SignNew(pathSource, pathTarget8, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA512, CryptoStandard.CADES, "Test", "Rheinau", crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0);

            this._txt.Text = "Signed successfully.";
        }
        else
        {
            this._txt.Text = "Certificate not found.";
        }
    }

    public void SignNew(String src, String dest,
             ICollection<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> chain, X509Certificate2 pk,
             String digestAlgorithm, CryptoStandard subfilter,
             String reason, String location,
             ICollection<ICrlClient> crlList,
             IOcspClient ocspClient,
             ITSAClient tsaClient,
             int estimatedSize)
    {
        // Creating the reader and the stamper
        PdfReader reader = null;
        PdfStamper stamper = null;
        FileStream os = null;
        try
        {
            reader = new PdfReader(src);
            os = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create);
            stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
            // Creating the appearance
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
            appearance.Reason = reason;
            appearance.Location = location;
            appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "Signature1");
            // Creating the signature
            IExternalSignature pks = new X509Certificate2Signature(pk, digestAlgorithm);
            MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this._txt.Text = e.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.Close();
            if (stamper != null)
                stamper.Close();
            if (os != null)
                os.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The SwissSign tool internally also uses iText(Sharp). Thus, there is something wrong in how you use the iTextSharp signing API. From the single code line you provided one can hardly deduce anything. Thus, please provide more code. Furthermore, you have signed including a giant CRL and a time stamp. Why not start simple and first create a signature without these additions and add them as soon as the basics work?

Comment: @mkl : thanks for your reply. Yes, regarding the CRL -> I was to rebuilding the same list in iTextSharp as when signing with the SwissSign tool.

Comment: Ok, but have you tried once without the list? If you did, did that succeed and produce a signature accepted By Adobe Reader?

Comment: @mkl : yes, I tried it without success. I always hoped that if I give all information than it would work... I was told that my public RSA exponent value of my signing certificate is quite unusual. It seems that the standard value is 0x010001, but mine is 0xFB95EC6D -> could that be a reason?

Comment: *I tried it without success* - Ah. Could you please supply a sample result of that? My problem is that your signature is gigantic (due to the embedded CRL), too big to easily spot an issue. *public RSA exponent value of my signing certificate is quite unusual* - That might indeed be an iossue for some verification libraries. I'll look into that..

Comment: @mkl : thanks for your support! I have uploaded the signed iTextSharp PDF without CRL, OCSP, TSA here: www.fitsch.com/hello-world_invalid_signed-with-itextsharp-without-crl.pdf

Comment: Ok, I found the issue in your signature but I'm not deep enough into .Net security to tell how to resolve it. Simply said your code claims to sign with RSA/2048 (according to the signer certificate) but the actual signature value is only a 1024 bit long. Whether the token for some reason created a RSA/1024 signature or whether half of a RSA/2048 signature has been lost, I cannot tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it's apparently the SwissSign CSP (cryptographic service provider; a layer that provides a bridge between the Windows system stores and the hardware device) which picks the wrong private key when using MSCAPI.

There seems no workaround to pick the correct private key in MSCAPI.

Therefore, I decided to use PKCS11 and NCryptroki library. Here the code:

```
using Cryptware.NCryptoki;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.log;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _07SignWithPKCS11DLL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoggerFactory.GetInstance().SetLogger(new SysoLogger());

            // Creates a Cryptoki object related to the specific PKCS#11 native library
            Cryptoki cryptoki = new Cryptoki("cvP11.dll");
            cryptoki.Initialize();

            // Reads the set of slots containing a token
            SlotList slots = cryptoki.Slots;
            if (slots.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No slot available");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            // Gets the first slot available
            Slot slot = slots[0];
            if (!slot.IsTokenPresent)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No token inserted in the slot: " + slots[0].Info.Description);
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }

            // Gets the first token available
            Token token = slot.Token;

            // Opens a read serial session
            Session session = token.OpenSession(Session.CKF_SERIAL_SESSION, null, null);

            // Executes the login passing the user PIN
            int nRes = session.Login(Session.CKU_USER, "secret");
            if (nRes != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong PIN");
                return;
            }

            CSignWithPKCS11SC.Smartcardsign(session, "PhilippEggerQualifiedSignature", "SwissSign_nonRep                ");

            /*
            CryptokiCollection template = new CryptokiCollection();
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_CLASS, CryptokiObject.CKO_CERTIFICATE));
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, Certificate.CKC_X_509));

            CryptokiCollection objects = session.Objects.Find(template, 10);

            // If the private keys is found continue
            if (objects.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Object obj in objects)
                {
                    Cryptware.NCryptoki.X509Certificate cert = (Cryptware.NCryptoki.X509Certificate)obj;
                    Console.WriteLine(cert.Label + " - " + cert.ID);
                }
            }
            */

            // Logouts and closes the session
            session.Logout();
            session.Close();
            cryptoki.Finalize(IntPtr.Zero);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class CryptokiPrivateKeySignature : IExternalSignature
    {
        private readonly Cryptware.NCryptoki.Session session;
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey;

        public CryptokiPrivateKeySignature(Session session, String alias)
        {
            this.session = session;
            CryptokiCollection template = new CryptokiCollection();
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_CLASS, CryptokiObject.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY));
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_KEY_TYPE, Key.CKK_RSA));
            // "SwissSign_nonRep                "
            // "SwissSign_digSig                "
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_LABEL, alias));

            /*
            CryptokiCollection objects = session.Objects.Find(template, 10);
            if (objects.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Object obj in objects)
                {
                    RSAPrivateKey cert = (RSAPrivateKey)obj;
                    Console.WriteLine(cert.Label);
                }
            }
            */

            privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey)session.Objects.Find(template);
        }

        public String GetHashAlgorithm()
        {
            return "SHA1";
        }

        public String GetEncryptionAlgorithm()
        {
            return "RSA";
        }

        public byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
        {
            session.SignInit(Mechanism.SHA1_RSA_PKCS, privateKey);
            return session.Sign(message);
        }
    }

    class CSignWithPKCS11SC
    {
        public const String SRC = @"C:\Temp\test_to_sign.pdf";
        public const String DEST = @"C:\Temp\test_to_sign-pkcs11.pdf";
        //public const String DLL = "c:/windows/system32/beidpkcs11.dll";
        public const String DLL = "c:/windows/system32/cvP11.dll";

        public void Sign(String src, String dest, ICollection<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> chain, Session session, String alias,
                         String digestAlgorithm, CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location,
                         ICollection<ICrlClient> crlList, IOcspClient ocspClient, ITSAClient tsaClient, int estimatedSize)
        {
            // Creating the reader and the stamper
            PdfReader reader = null;
            PdfStamper stamper = null;
            FileStream os = null;
            try
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(src);
                os = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create);
                stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
                // Creating the appearance
                PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
                appearance.Reason = reason;
                appearance.Location = location;
                appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
                // Creating the signature
                IExternalSignature pks = new CryptokiPrivateKeySignature(session, alias);
                MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.Close();
                if (stamper != null)
                    stamper.Close();
                if (os != null)
                    os.Close();
            }
        }


        public static void Smartcardsign(Session session, String alias, String aliasPrivateKey)
        {
            // Searchs for an RSA certificate object
            // Sets the template with its attributes
            CryptokiCollection template = new CryptokiCollection();
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_CLASS, CryptokiObject.CKO_CERTIFICATE));
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, Certificate.CKC_X_509));
            template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_LABEL, alias));

            Cryptware.NCryptoki.X509Certificate nCert = (Cryptware.NCryptoki.X509Certificate)session.Objects.Find(template);

            if (nCert != null)
            {

                X509Certificate2 cert = Utils.ConvertCertificate(nCert);
                ICollection<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> chain = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>();
                X509Chain x509chain = new X509Chain();
                x509chain.Build(cert);

                foreach (X509ChainElement x509ChainElement in x509chain.ChainElements)
                {
                    chain.Add(DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509ChainElement.Certificate));
                }

                IOcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
                List<ICrlClient> crlList = new List<ICrlClient>();
                crlList.Add(new CrlClientOnline(chain));
                TSAClientBouncyCastle tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle("http://tsa.swisssign.net");

                CSignWithPKCS11SC app = new CSignWithPKCS11SC();

                Console.WriteLine("Logged in? " + session.IsLoggedIn);

                app.Sign(SRC, DEST, chain, session, aliasPrivateKey, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, CryptoStandard.CMS,
                        "Test", "Rheinau", crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Certificate not found: " + alias);
            }
        }
    }
}
```